# Configure PHPStorm

Tags: netbeans, phpstorm

I'm new to PhpStorm. I have PHPstorm 3.0 the latest version. In the netbeans IDE that I used to code in, I just click run and it will show it in browser using my localhost and that is applicable for all php projects.

Any help to specify a One-For-All configuration that could let me focus on my code ;-) same as NetBeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a server configured, you can use **Open in Browser** context menu for the current file, or you can create a **PHP Web Application** Run/Debug configuration for a fixed URL.

Comment: so how can i configure a local server (localhost) in phpstorm ?

Comment: See http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/deployment-connection-tab.html, use Local (In-Place) deployment.

Comment: For PHP Web Application debugging refer to http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/servers-2.html.

Comment: thanks. I did it by using local or mounted folder, it was a long procedure, but I did it. Thanks a lot for your help.